# How to add initial Values in field from redux-form if I use map for create array values

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

How to add initial Values in field from redux-form if I use map for create array values.It is my code.
I'm trying to create an initial value for a field named longHours

```
{this.state.tem.map((value, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className="d-flex justify-content-start humanOnProject align-items-center">
                        <img src={this.state.tem[index].img} className="humanLogo" />
                        <div className="reSelect">
                            <Select
                                options={peoples}
                                value={value}
                                name="form-field-re"
                                clearable={false}
                                onChange={(selectedOption) => this.reChange(selectedOption, index)}
                                className="reSelectHuman"
                            />
                            <div className="HumanPosition">{this.state.tem[index].position}</div>
                        </div>
                        <Field name={`Tems[${index}].temstart`} type="text" component={TemStartproject} />
                        <Field
                            name={`Tems[${index}].longHours`}
                            type="text"
                            component="input"
                            className="longHours"/>
                        <button type="button" title="Remove Member" onClick={() => this.removeArry(index)} className="deleteBtn" />
                    </div>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just map value to initialValues props

```
connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.formdata
  }),
  {  } 
)(Component)
```

more information

https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/initializefromstate/

if your field in array then need to FieldArray name with index

like

```
{ fieldArrayName : [{temstart: 'data', longHour : 122323 }]}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но этот метод работает только тогда, когда я не переписываю состояние, когда я его меняю, тогда новое состояние не освобождает начальное satate

Comment: enable  enableReinitialize  like  reduxForm({
  form: 'simple' , enableReinitialize : true
})(SimpleForm)